# Is there a jsonb_array_elements equivalent in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I recently moved onto Snowflake and I'm trying to expand my JSON string similar to the jsonb_array_elements function in Postgres. Below is an example of what I have before any manipulations, we can call this table mytable

```
id            date              cost              details
123        2020-02-01           30      {"currency": "USD", "name":"John Smith", "items":[{"type":"hat", "value":"20"}, {"type":"tshirt", "value" : "10"}]}
```

Normally I'd run the following code in postgres

```
SELECT
  id,
  date,
  cost as total_cost,
  jsonb_array_elements(details->'items') as details
from mytable
```

To get the following output:

```
id            date              total_cost              details
123        2020-02-01              30             {"type":"hat" , "value":"20"}
123        2020-02-01              30           {"type":"tshirt" , "value":"10"}
```

I can then parse out **type** and **value** into their own columns.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Snowflake?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to get that output. Using the ***FLATTEN*** table function in a ***LATERAL*** join.

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.date,
  t.cost as total_cost,
  f.*
from mytable t
 , lateral flatten (input => t.details:items) f
```

This is the most basic syntax for what you need. Explore more of this function as it is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to reproduce what `jsonb_array_elements` was doing. 
You need to use FLATTEN, check [this](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) documentation for reference.

In your specific case, you will do something like this

```
SELECT 
  id,
  date,
  cost AS total_cost,
  value AS details,
  get_path(value, 'type')::VARCHAR as item_type,
  get_path(value, 'value')::FLOAT as item_cost
FROM my_table AS t,
   lateral flatten(input => parse_json(t.details), path => 'items') f
```

Comment: Thanks Nico! This worked, if I had a second array within details and I applied lateral flatten to that. This second lateral flatten produces repeat values. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Can you post an example? Not sure if I got your question.